# Replacing all bullet points with check boxes in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

So here is my problem I am currently facing. The report I am working with has bullets points(wingdings) being used as check boxes. I am trying to make a script to find and replace all bullets with activex check boxes here is what little code I have:

```
Sub RemoveBulletsInsertCB()
Dim objParagraph As Paragraph
Dim objDoc As Document

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

  For Each objParagraph In objDoc.Paragraphs
   If objParagraph.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet Then
   objParagraph.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
   'Call insertCB


End If
  Next objParagraph

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set objDoc = Nothing
End Sub



Public Sub insertCB()



Set myOB = Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1")
With myOB.OLEFormat
.Activate
Set myObj = .Object
End With
With myObj
'now you can name the field anything you want
 .Name = ("CB1")
 .value = False
 'delete the caption, or have it say what you want
 .Caption = ""
 .Height = 11.5
 .width = 18
End With
```

End Sub

The above code does a good job removing the bullets, but I would like to replace it with an activex checkbox without any caption.

Also when I want to replace the bullets with the activex checkboxes, the insertCB code only works once.

I hope my problem is understandable and thank you in advance.

Comment: Cindy, the reason for the ActiveX check box is because I am running the script to try and convert this document to a digital Operating Procedure.  Who ever wrote the original procedure used the square bullets as check marks....

Comment: there are few types of checkboxes available in Word - Content Control, Legacy Forms, ActiveX, HTML, etc. so maybe the question was about the ActiveX choice over the more "native" options. I would recommend Record Macro to see if the generated code gives any hints

Comment: I was asking "why ActiveX" because unless you need the Forms functionality there are (IMO) better alternatives. Put a different way: What should happen in the document when these checkboxes are selected? Should code run? Is it only visual? Should other code be able to easily evaluate? Should data mining be performed at some point on the document to extract information? I'm trying to determine whether it makes sense for you/us to put effort into ActiveX when a differnt kind of checkbox might be better suited.

Comment: @BillWoodward ActiveX is also discouraged due to security problems. Many companies even have their network policies set to not run them. Unless there is a compelling reason to use them, consider another control. Word's Content Controls are the preferred means now.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you, There is no functionality to the check boxes other than being able show the step has been executed. From what ForEachLoop has stated. It is probably  best to stay away from the ActiveX check boxes.

Comment: @BillWoodward Agreed. What's still not clear to me is whether you're generating this, or the user needs to click? Sounds like you're generating it with no user interaction? If yes, my recommendation would be a static symbol (font character, similar to the bullet idea, but more "checkbox-y" and not a bullet (unless that's what you want)). Content controls can work, as well, but are more "overhead".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basic way to approach replacing the bullets with a character checkbox. I've chosen from Insert/Symbol - there are a number of possibilities in that dialog box. You can just record a macro to get the information for the one you want.

A similar approach can also be used for a ContentControl, if you decide you prefer that.

Notice the use of a `Range` object and how it's "collapsed" to its starting point to get the beginning of the Paragraph.

If you also need an indent you need to apply that to the paragraph. I *highly* recommend you define and apply a STLYE for this purpose - don't apply the formatting directly.

```
Sub RemoveBulletsInsertCB()
    Dim objParagraph As Paragraph
    Dim rng As word.Range
    Dim objDoc As Document

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

      For Each objParagraph In objDoc.Paragraphs
       If objParagraph.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet Then
            Set rng = objParagraph.Range
            rng.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers

            insertCB rng
       End If
      Next objParagraph

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Set objDoc = Nothing
End Sub   

Public Sub insertCB(rng As word.Range)
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    rng.InsertSymbol Font:="Wingdings", CharacterNumber:=-3842, Unicode _
        :=True
End Sub
```

Comment: That is great! Thank you so much...I understand where I was going wrong now.